# jQuery does not respond to radio checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I want a box to appear in jQuery when I check the radio, but I did not mark and nothing happens.

Here are the codes.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://sites.google.com/site/lightdownloads154/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://sites.google.com/site/lightdownloads154/jquery.alerts.css" type="text/css" />

<center><textarea rows="10" cols="17" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" wrap="soft">- Todos os links e arquivos que se encontram no blog, estão hospedados na própria Internet, somente indicamos onde se encontra.

- Qualquer arquivo protegido por algum tipo de lei deve permanecer, no máximo, 24 horas em seu computador.

- Eles podem ser baixados apenas para teste, devendo o usuário apagá-lo ou compra-lo após 24 horas.

- A aquisição desses arquivos pela internet é de única e exclusiva responsabilidade do usuário.

- Os donos, webmasters e qualquer outra pessoa que tenha relacionamento com a produção do blog não tem responsabilidade alguma sobre os arquivos que o usuário venha a baixar e para que ira utiliza-los.
</textarea><center>
<center>
<input name="accept" type="radio" id="accept" /> Eu aceito <input name="refuse" type="radio" id="refuse" /> Não aceito </center></center>
</center>
```

​
JavaScript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#accept").click(function() {
          jAlert($('input[name=accept]:checked').attr('Obrigado por aceitar os Termos.'));
      });

      $("#refuse").click(function() {
          jAlert('refuse', 'Se não aceita os termos de uso retire-se do blog.', 'Termos de uso');
      });
  });
```

​
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/neto737/XkBSv/)

Comment: You haven't closed your ready event handler. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XkBSv/4/).

Comment: Your radio-s have to have the same name, but different value to work - http://jsfiddle.net/XkBSv/10/

Comment: close document.ready and what is jAlert?

Comment: @Juhana : The plugin he includes in the first line in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This basically fixes your code: http://jsfiddle.net/XkBSv/7/

- <strike>jAlert is not defined in your script, you propably haven't included an external script for that.</strike>
- jAlert is causing a syntax error.
- you haven't closed your ready event causing a syntax error.

you probably also want to change the input names to the same value so they can actually act as radio buttons.

**UPDATE**

The syntax error in jAlert is probably because it has no `;` before the closure, if I add the code before your code instead of a link in the html it does work!

see http://jsfiddle.net/XkBSv/13/

Comment: this is not what I want, I need the alert is in jQuery, I'll show you where I got the code of the warning, but I can not install it on radios.

Code of jQuery Alert: [Click here][1]


  [1]: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

Answer (score 0):

1. Google is redirecting the requests to these files to an HTML file which is why you are getting the error: `uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` or not experiencing any JavaScript execution past this point.

   https://sites.google.com/site/lightdownloads154/jquery.alerts.js
   https://sites.google.com/site/lightdownloads154/jquery.alerts.css

   Use the following:

   http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.js
   http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.css
2. This line does nothing:

   `$('input[name=accept]:checked').attr('Obrigado por aceitar os Termos.')`

   jQuery is looking for an attribute with the name `Obrigado por ...` and since it doesn't exist is returning nothing.
3. You need to group radio buttons with the same name attribute and differentiate by using the value attribute.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/MXZJJ/

Comment: in this example would I change the message and the title of AlertBox?

Comment: I am not sure what is supposed to happen. Remember to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: helped me a lot, but I need to change the title and the message is in AlertBox :(

Comment: @NetoMello For that read the documentation: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/ Please accept and up vote. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <link href="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/jquery.alerts.js"></script>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $("#accept").change(function() {
                        if($(this).attr("checked")){
                            jAlert('This is a custom alert box', 'Radio accept selected');
                        }

                    });

                    $("#refuse").change(function() {
                        if($(this).attr("checked")){
                            jAlert('This is a custom alert box', 'Radio refuse selected');

                        }

                    });


                });

            </script>
        </head>
        <body style="font-size:62.5%;">

        <input  type="radio" name = "radioGroup" id="accept" value="accepted" /> Accepted
<input  type="radio" name = "radioGroup" id="refuse" value="rejected" /> Not Accepted </center></center>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: `$(this).attr("checked")`  isn't the correct way to check if checked. `$(this).prop("checked")` is the most reliable method.

Comment: @Neto Mello i have edited the above code for you and added name attributes to radio buttons. If you have more than one radio buttons and want only one to be selected at one time you have to assign a value to the name attribute of the radio button and the value have to be same for that group of radio buttons.

Comment: giving continues to select the two.

Comment: @NetoMello did you update this line: <input  type="radio" name = "radioGroup" id="accept" value="accepted" /> Accepted
<input  type="radio" name = "radioGroup" id="refuse" value="rejected" /> Not Accepted </center></center>
Double check you dont have two 'name' attributes on your radio buttons. There should be only one name attribute. this code works 100%.

Comment: @NetoMello My correct answer has -1 against it and you never accepted the answer as correct. I spent time to help you with your problem and you help me out by getting rid of that -1 and accepting the answer as correct so that it works for both of us. Cheers :)